# Splitting file in equal size files and give these files as input to a shell script which should run parallely

Tags: shell, scripting

I want to split a file of 10000 records into number of files with equal size of records.These new files need to be given as input to a shell script. Shell script should run in parallel for each file. Can we use any looping here?

Comment: splitting part of your question, you can refer to this question [split file into N pieces with same name but different target directories](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/401387/72456).

Comment: Have a look at `man split` and have a try with option `-l`. If you can't succeed, edit the question to show what you tried and maybe give an easy example.

Comment: Try `parallel -a myfile --pipepart --block -1 wc` or 
`parallel -a myfile --pipepart --block -1 --cat wc` or 
`parallel -a myfile --pipepart --block -1 --fifo wc`.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your data file is called `data.txt` and the script you want to run is called `script.sh`. Then you could do something like the following:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Create a temporary directory
splitdir="$(mktemp -d)"

# Splite the data-file into files of 1000 lines each
split --lines=1000 -d --suffix-length=3 data.txt "${splitdir}/chunk"

# Run your script on each data file separately
for chunk in "${splitdir}/"*; do nohup script.sh "${chunk}" &; done
```

You could also do something similar using [xargs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs) or [GNU parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_parallel) instead of a Bash loop.